# Trying to check for content in my Hash but getting "undefined method `&' for Hash" error

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm writing a Ruby on rails (5) application.  I was trying to simplify this block

```
if my_hash_data[:my_key_1]
  my_hash_data[:my_key_1][:my_key_2]
else
  ""
end
```

and so I wrote

```
my_hash_data[:my_key_1]&[:my_key_2] || ""
```

However this results in an

```
undefined method `&' for {:my_key_2=>"Y"}:Hash
```

error.  Is there another way I can write this to cut down on the lines I'm using?

Comment: what is your ruby version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what you're trying to do

```
my_hash_data[:my_key_1]&.[](:my_key_2) || ""
```

but I suggest using [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) from ruby 2.3 onward

```
my_hash_data.dig(:my_key_1, :my_key_2) || ""
```

Remember that `h[:foo]` is syntactic sugar for `h.[](:foo)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be using an older version of ruby which Hash may not have either safe navigation or dig methods so you may just try

```
 my_hash_data[:my_key_1] ? my_hash_data[:my_key_1][:my_key_2] : ''
```